scalpel segfualts
I'm on a relatively recent install of Jammy Jellyfish, trying to run scalpel on a hikvision security system hard drive. Smart data analysis checks out fine. I can see the data with hexdump -C /dev/sda | less
Ive run the program on other installations, but every time, I run it on this system it segfaults.
Purged, reinstalled, checked the config file. It starts, writes the audit log file, and segfaults. scalpel version 1.60.
I installed foremost as well, when I read the is based on note.
Scalpel version 1.60
Written by Golden G. Richard III, based on Foremost 0.69.

Opening target "/dev/sda"

Segmentation fault (core dumped)


Heres the last bit of what strace has to say about it:
brk(0x58f0558bf000)                     = 0x58f0558bf000
read(3, "-------------------------\n# Scan"..., 4096) = 471
brk(0x58f0558e3000)                     = 0x58f0558e3000
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=46, ws_col=186, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3552, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3552, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 3552
lseek(3, -2260, SEEK_CUR)               = 1292
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2260
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/media/h/98a20942-1b42-4c6c-9db9-9df1420cb5f2/puddle", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
brk(0x58f055909000)                     = 0x58f055909000
getdents64(3, 0x58f0558e09b0 /* 2 entries */, 32768) = 48
getdents64(3, 0x58f0558e09b0 /* 0 entries */, 32768) = 0
brk(0x58f055901000)                     = 0x58f055901000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/media/h/98a20942-1b42-4c6c-9db9-9df1420cb5f2/puddle/audit.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
readlink("/dev", 0x7fff23a9c180, 1023)  = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
readlink("/dev/sda", 0x7fff23a9c180, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(2, "\nOpening target \"/dev/sda\"\n\n", 28
Opening target "/dev/sda"

) = 28
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=NULL} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)



SEGFAULT = programming error, or hardware error. Have you tried running a different version? Is system memory good (maybe do a run of memtest)?

Also, I don't know what the thing does, but make sure you're running it as root; it's opening a device file, so root is needed.

@kos, yeah I used a version in Antix linux, and on Kali, and there, this software works as expected. scalpel is a tool that can read / recover files, by looking at the headers and footers of files, or in the way im trying, by reading through the block device looking for file identifiers. Kinda like what the command file does, looking at magic numbers.

I mean, I got the data, by spinning up an antix boot disk, and writing a lil script to dump all the found files to a root dir. ... anyway, the version reports the same version, on both kali, antix, and ubuntu, but on Ubuntu, it doesn't work.
